# Grails 3 : exExecute a job after saving to the database

Tags: java, grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have a job done with the quartz plugin, but I would like to run it only if my User table contains users with active status.

Thank you

Comment: you can only check for those users in the beginning of your job

Answer (score 0):

> I have a job done with the quartz plugin, but I would like to run it
> only if my User table contains users with active status.

There isn't enough information here to know for sure what the right thing to do is but one thing to consider is you can schedule the Quartz job to run at whatever frequency you like and have the job query the database regarding user active status, and then the job can react accordingly.

Comment: the job execution frequency is when a new record is made in the user table

Comment: "the job execution frequency is when a new record is made in the user table" - Then you probably don't want to schedule a job.  An asynchronous event listener on that domain would make more sense.

Comment: Why is it that you want to involve Quartz?

Comment: At https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-events-demo/blob/261f25652e5fead8563ed83f7903e52dfb37fb40/src/main/groovy/gorm/events/demo/listener/AuditListener.groovy#L21-L26 is an example of a Hibernate event listener in a Grails app.  That particular one is listening for pre-update events but you could listen for insert.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I am gonna try an asynchronous event listener

Comment: "Thanks Jeff, I am gonna try an asynchronous event listener" - Awesome.  If you have any trouble or would like to see an example that does something specific, let me know.  Happy to help.

Comment: asynchronous event listener? Thats called a 'webhook'. There used to be a community plugin for that but they are no longer supported with the EOL of all other version of Grails.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a webhook; after a put/post/delete (ie idempotent call), you call another endpoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).